# how many dimensions can java array have? With size of each dimension?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was recently created one augmented big array which maps multidimensional array into a 1D-array. see this post on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230223/java-creating-augmented-array-of-size-40-00-00-000)!.

The size of the resultant augmented array is dependent on the number of dimensions of array. what is the maximum number of dimensions that you can use when declaring an array?

Is there a size issue related to higher dimensions of array?

For Example -

### valid

```
int arr[][] = new int[10000][10000];
```

### invalid (throws OutOfMemoryException)

```
int arr[][][]= new int[10000][10000][10000];
```

What is the allowed number of dimensions of array in java ? and
what is the size of the array as per the number of dimensions of an array ?

Comment: Also consider the part size issue with multidimensional array

Comment: What do you mean by part size? The size of each dimension?

Comment: Yeah I observed that size of each dimensional decreases as number of dimensions increases.

Comment: Well you're reaching the memory limit (you're getting an `OutOfMemoryException`) before you hit the dimension cap of 255. So yes, if you want to have a higher-dimension array (without increasing the memory set aside for the JVM), you'll have to reduce the size of each dimension.

Comment: If reduce the size of each dimension then what’s meaning of my augmented array. Please do check that link

Comment: "[...] what’s meaning of my augmented array." I don't understand, sorry. What do you mean by "augmented array"? The `BigArray` proposed in the link? And that approach is one you've worked out, not me, so you should be the one describing the "meaning of it" :-).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but bigArray is nxn multidimensional array and Im treating it as 1-D array so if n=integer.max then resultant array is far much larger than maximum 1-D array allowed i.e int.max size array . But Java doesn’t allow me to put int.max bigArray . Maximum n  I can use was 20000 for 2D and 1000 for 3D array

Comment: Well, as you're describing you're getting an `OutOfMemoryException` when you use `n=Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Take a second to think about the numbers. With `n=Integer.MAX_VALUE`, your 2D `int[][]` array would hold ~2.1bio x ~2.1bio integers --- a HUGE number of entries. Multiple that number by 4 to get the number of bytes it takes up in memory (each int is 4 bytes). There's no way that's going to fit in memory.